# c# omnisharp intellisense not working with net 5.0 in vscode (windows 10)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

vscode version:          1.54.2 (user setup)

visual studio version :  16.8.6

c# omniSharp version :   1.23.9

intellisense is not working in .net5
and also when trying to generate assets for build and debug this error pops up:

Error : Unable to generate assets to build and debug. OmniSharp server is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your Omnisharp Project Load Timeout as the server might not able to start before the load Timeout so it just cancels the server startup process.

I've changed mine to 10000 to be able to properly wait for the server to startup before automatically stoping the operation and that seems to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have current .net, as well as current sdk. You will need to download these online. Then, in vs.code go to file > preferences > settings and search for settings.json. This will give you the settings for your vs.code. delete all present omnisharp settings. reinstall current c# in extensions. You may have to restart for settings to implement. Dont forget CTRL + SHIFT + P, where you can search ommnisharp and restart.